# How to create icon in windows taskbar in Java (NOT in System tray)?

Tags: java, taskbar

Windows Taskbar and NOT System Tray:

[image: Windows Taskbar and NOT System Tray]

Please tell me how to create an icon in windows task bar in Java? I can only find the solutions for System Tray. As shown in the image, I want icon on task bar.

Answer (score 1):

When you use JFrame, you can set icons for that like this :

```
List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
icons.add(new ImageIcon("16.png").getImage());
icons.add(new ImageIcon("32.png").getImage());
frame.setIconImages(icons);
```

Also when you change JFrame icon, that icon will show in windows taskbar too.

This tested in Windows 7 running Java 7